# What is more expensive - having 1.0 filter_size and use_filter_size_min = False or 0.1 filter size and use_filter_size_min = True?

Tags: python, texturing, interpolation

Working with blender 2.79.

I'm trying to improve the quality of the jagged edges of the texture by having as few computation resources spent as possible (even 50ms difference is important).

After rendering, the texture looks good with these settings:

```py
texture.use_mipmap = True
texture.filter_type = 'BOX'
texture.filter_size = 1.0
```

However, it turns out it increased processing time a lot compared to the old solution, where the filter size was smaller (which makes sense):

```py
texture.filter_size = 0.1
```

After checking API I found that there is neat option

```
use_filter_size_min = True
```

That improves quality greatly in my case, with a `0.1` `filter_size` value!

The question is, what exactly `use_filter_size_min` does and is it better to have it `True` with a smaller `filter_size`, or is there some hidden expensive thing going on under the hood?
From my understanding, yes, it's better to keep a smaller `filter_size`, but I'm not sure.

Unfortunately, I can't measure performance reliably right now, only quality, so I'd like to hear opinions and suggestions. Thank you.